# Elixir/Phoenix change livereload endpoint

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am serving an app behind nginx proxy, and want to preserve phoenix live reload features. The issue is with:

```
<iframe src="/phoenix/live_reload/frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

That is added to the main html. I need to change it to:

```
<iframe src="/new_url/phoenix/live_reload/frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

I have checked endpoint, and tried to change like this:

```
if code_reloading? do
  socket "/new_url/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
  plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
  plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
end
```

But it doesn't seem to change the iframe url. Then I found `livereloader.ex` in my deps, which I guess allows to set the url with config.

Can someone show how should I set the url for it? Thanks in advance.

Updated the `config/dev.exs`, yet doesn't seem to work.As pointed out by @PatNowak,the url seems to set host and port, but not the url.

Last: 
I believe that setting url, as suggested below, changes the socket url, but not actually the `iframe src`. I'll remove proxy for now to keep the live reload.

Comment: Try adding `url: "/new_url/phoenix/live_reload/socket"` after `patterns: [...]` in `config/dev.exs` in the `live_reload` config line.

Comment: Hey@Dogbert, I've added it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to change the url.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the config? Can you add the updated config to the question?

Comment: Yep, restarted the server. But I might be wrong about the url, as pointed out by @PatNowak, the line sets host and port, but not the url. Please have a look at his answer

Comment: Try adding `url: [path: "/new_url"]` to `config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint` config.

Comment: @Dogbert it seems to be that `url:` changes the socket url for reloading, but not the `iframe src`. Maybe it is not possible to change the src directly with config? Anyways thanks for your help, I'll remove the proxy for now.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ please use code blocks to post the code, not screenshots. It’s a general SO rule, that is clearly stated in ToS.

Answer (score 0):

You found a place where `config[:url]` is set, but you missed a comment in the `live_reloader.ex`. Please check [that](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload/blob/master/lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex#L38) line. There's presented how this url should looks like.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link! I've tried to do this, but it seems to only set host/port and not the url part after, even when I pass it like this: ` url: "ws://localhost:8080/new_url/"` it still returns standard path when restarting the server

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this issue in the year 2022, and using `phoenix_live_reload 1.3.3`, then the way to change the `src` attr on iframe is to pass `iframe_attrs` in your `dev.exs`:

```
config :myapp, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ..
    ],
    url: "/new_url/phoenix/live_reload/frame",
    iframe_attrs: [
      src: "/new_url/phoenix/live_reload/frame",
    ]
  ]
```

It might be good idea to change the `url` to the same value as `src`, as the `url` attr is used to set the [Socket connection in JS.](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload/blob/v1.3.3/lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex#L98)

**OR.....**

The Nginx conf is incorrect (the OP hadn't posted theirs tho), and therefore it's all possible within Nginx and without messing about with your `dev.exs` config.

I was having similar issue where my local Phoenix app is behind proxy at `demo.example.com`.

My nginx conf:

```
server {
  server_name demo.example.com;
  listen 80;

  location / {
    # your other proxy settings here
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.3:4000/demo$request_uri;
  }
```

Don't forget the `router.ex` changes:

```
scope "/demo", MyAppWeb do
   # whatever
   get "/contact", SomeController, :contact
end
```

So in this setup all requests like `demo.example.com/contact` will get to their exact routes. **However, live sockets and live reloads don't work.**

Let's update our nginx.conf to pass all `/live` and `/phoenix` requests to top-level router:

```
location ~ (live|phoenix) {
  # remember to set proxy settings to support websockets here

  # pass requests as top-level
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.3:4000$request_uri;
}
```

This way live reload works during development and behind Nginx reverse proxy without changing iframe's src etc.